# Server Push not working on Repeat View

Tags: css, performance, http2, server-push, web-performance

We're using the `Link` header to preload our font files and it's working great when the browser cache is empty. However on "Repeat View" the font files are loaded twice and Chrome shows a warning message. How can we fix that?

The `Link` header and the CSS files both point to the full relative URL:

```
/app/themes/foobar/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.woff
```

First View:

[image: First View]

Repeat View:

[image: Repeat View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing `crossorigin`, so instead of:

`Link: </path/to/font.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font`

Use:

`Link: </path/to/font.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font; crossorigin`